# Comparing equality of groupby objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Say we have dataframe one `df1` and dataframe two `df2`.

```
import pandas as pd

dict1= {'group':['A','A','B','C','C','C'],'col2':[1,7,4,2,1,0],'col3':[1,1,3,4,5,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1).set_index('group')

dict2 = {'group':['A','A','B','C','C','C'],'col2':[1,7,400,2,1,0],'col3':[1,1,3,4,5,3500]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict2).set_index('group')

df1
       col2  col3
group            
A         1     1
A         7     1
B         4     3
C         2     4
C         1     5
C         0     3


df2
       col2  col3
group            
A         1     1
A         7     1
B       400     3
C         2     4
C         1     5
C         0  3500
```

In pandas it is easy to compare the equality of these two dataframes with `df1.equals(df2)`. In this case `False`.

However, we can see that some in this groups (`A` in the given toy example) are equal and some are not (groups `B` and `C`). I want to check for equality between these groups. In other words, check the equality between the dataframes with index `A` and `B` etc.

Here is my attempt. We wish to group the data

```
 g1 = df1.groupby('group')
 g2 = df2.groupby('group')
```

Naively trying `g1.equals(g2)` gives the error `Cannot access callable attribute 'equals' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`.

However, if we try

```
 g1.apply(lambda x: x.equals(g2))
```

We get a series

```
group
A    False
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

However the first entry should be `True` since the first case group `A` is equal between the two dataframes.

I can see that I could laboriously construct nested loops to do this, but that's slow. I feel there a way to do this in `pandas` without usings loops? I think I am misusing the `apply` method?

Comment: You can do something like `[g1.get_group(g[0]).equals(g2.get_group(g[0])) for g in g1 ]` which works but has some obvious flaws (e.g. different groups, different number of groups etc)

Comment: in `lambda x: x.equals(g2)` you're checking if a single row `x` of `g1` is equal to the whole of `g2` which is why it's coming back as False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `get_group` on `g2` to retrieve the group to compare, you can access the group name using the attribute `.name`:

```
In[316]:
g1.apply(lambda x: x.equals(g2.get_group(x.name)))

Out[316]: 
group
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

**EDIT**

To handle non-existent groups:

```
In[320]:
g1.apply(lambda x: x.equals(g2.get_group(x.name)) if x.name in g2.groups else False)

Out[320]: 
group
A     True
B    False
C    False
dtype: bool
```

Example:

```
In[323]:
dict1= {'group':['A','A','B','C','C','C','D'],'col2':[1,7,4,2,1,0,-1],'col3':[1,1,3,4,
                                                               5,3,-1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict1).set_index('group')
g1 = df1.groupby('group')

g1.apply(lambda x: x.equals(g2.get_group(x.name)) if x.name in g2.groups else False)

Out[323]: 
group
A     True
B    False
C    False
D    False
dtype: bool
```

Here `.groups` returns a dict of the groups, the keys are the group name/labels, we can test for existence using `x.name in g2.groups` and modify the lambda to handle non-existent groups

Comment: `g2.get_group` Pandas never fails to enlighten me

Comment: Just notice this will fail if *every* group in `g1` is not in `g2`

Comment: @RafaelC true but that was never part of the original problem

Comment: @EdChum not criticizing, just some heads up to OP

Comment: If we were to expand the scope of the question to include the case where every group of `g1` is not in `g2` and that would return `False` in the return. How would we go about that?

Comment: @EdChum awesome :) +1

Comment: Fantastic answer, super insightful. Thanks @EdChum